# Not able to update my.ini file on Windows mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to enable federated engine in mysql.For this I try to update my.ini file but my changes are not getting reflected on restarting the mysql service. I found that no matter whatever i put in my.ini the changes don't get reflected at all.
On googling i found a bug : MySQL Bugs: #49008: Applying changes to my.ini doesn't work
Is there any workaround for this without upgrading mysql?

Comment: Have you stopped MySQL before trying to edit the ini file?

Comment: Yes i edited after stopping mysql service and then started the service but changes never get reflected.